# Realm and RxSwift connectivity

Tags: realm, swift3, rx-swift

I've been looking at options for persistence when using RxSwift and Realm was looking attractive due to it's relative simplicity and the availability of some extensions in the community repo.

Unfortunately although I can get Realm and RxSwift working nicely in Xcode 8b6, things of seriously wrong as soon as you try to connect them together as RxRealm does not currently compile (there seems to be more going wrong with it than the Grand Renaming as far as I can tell).

Is there a workaround that is reliable? I can't believe for a moment that there isn't, I just can't find a resource at present. I was thinking of converting the Result object into an Set or Array and making this Observable but. I'm not sure if the contents (Realm Objects) are going to be handled correctly. Knowing my luck, I suspect not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Pull Request towards the RxRealm project adding Swift 3 support: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm/pull/26

I suggest you try using that.

---

More generally, targeting an Xcode beta will by definition give you a less stable software ecosystem, since no one is submitting apps with that and it's a moving target (often with weekly breaking changes). So if you want stable software, use stable tools. Realm and RxRealm both support Swift 2.2 quite well, so using that will give you the best experience.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'll give this code base a try. I do totally understand the downsides of trying to keep at the 'bleeding edge' of what is a rapidly evolving language. Perhaps somewhat foolishly I thought it would be better to be fully up to speed with all the changes as they happen but I must admit the Swift 2.2 -> 3 transition has been by far the most painful yet and has cost me a lot of time when trying to integrate non-Apple frameworks. Lesson learned for next time I guess!